# How to search for all contacts without a tag? Registered for event

Tags: tags, search-builder

I need to find all contacts that are in our system without a tag AND are Individuals AND registered for a specific event.

This is what I am doing:

- Contact -> Contact Type = Individual
- Participant -> Event Title =  Event Name
- Contacts -> Tags = Is Empty

Then I error out - the issue is with the tags - even if I choose *Is Null* - I still get a ton of errors.  If I chose Contacts -> Tags -> Not In -> Select every tag.  I still get a ton of errors.

PS: Is there a way to use search builder to find an event by Event ID instead of title?

CiviCRM 5.0.2 and Drupal 7

DB Error: No Such Field - Backtrace below.

---

```
    #0 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(190): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: no such field", -19, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, ...")
#4 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-19, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, ...")
#5 [internal function](): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -19, NULL, NULL, "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, ...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(224): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:8))
#7 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#8 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -19, NULL, NULL, "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, ...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#9 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-19, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1054 ** Unknown column 'civicrm_tag.name' in 'field list'")
#10 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#11 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, ...")
#12 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2446): DB_common->query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, ...")
#13 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1635): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, ...")
#14 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(392): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, ...")
#15 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1348): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, ...", TRUE)
#16 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(4942): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, ...")
#17 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Selector.php(1181): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->searchQuery(NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
#18 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/PagerAToZ.php(108): CRM_Contact_Selector->alphabetQuery()
#19 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/PagerAToZ.php(136): CRM_Utils_PagerAToZ::getDynamicCharacters(Object(CRM_Contact_Selector), FALSE)
#20 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/PagerAToZ.php(52): CRM_Utils_PagerAToZ::createLinks(Object(CRM_Contact_Selector), NULL, FALSE)
#21 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search.php(839): CRM_Utils_PagerAToZ::getAToZBar(Object(CRM_Contact_Selector), NULL)
#22 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Builder.php(414): CRM_Contact_Form_Search->postProcess()
#23 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(447): CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Builder->postProcess()
#24 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Refresh.php(75): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#25 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Refresh->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Builder), "refresh")
#26 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Builder), "refresh")
#27 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("refresh")
#28 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(309): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:4), (Array:0))
#29 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#30 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#31 /home/webname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(445): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#32 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("contact", "search", "builder")
#33 /home/webname/www/www/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:3))
#34 /home/webname/www/www/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#35 {main}
```

Comment: (Sorry I cannot add a comment)
Fine, thank you very much for this possibility! Is there y way to save a custom search or should I always reenter the group to include and the group or tags to exclude ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While a code-level fix is obviously preferable, the quick solution is to create two groups:

- Everyone who attended the event who has the tag.
- Everyone who attended the event.

Then use the custom search **Include/Exclude by Group/Tag** to include group 2 and exclude group 1.  Who's left is everyone who attended without the tag.

Comment: Thanks Jon! That worked for me - had to make yet another group so I could display the results to my liking.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your question that allowed me to test Jon's solution and now find an alternative solution that seems to me even simpler:

The new SearchKit allows you to do what you want easily.
The simplest is to choose "Without" from the first drop-down menu and "Tag" from the second drop-down menu.
Then we can combine tags to different criteria, like Individual. However, I did not test with events.

Comment: I agree that this is the preferred solution in 2024.