# After upgrade to 5.0.2 from 4.7.30 getting "DB Error: No such field" on queries

Tags: upgrade, database, search-builder, 5.0

Since updating my CiviCRM 4.7.30 on WordPress 4.9.5, I am getting "DB Error: No such field" when doing queries through Advanced Search or Search Builder.  Some of the problems where when I was trying to use a Profile to view an Advanced Search and others were related to fields that I was trying to search by (my assumption is that they are fields that need lookups, but I haven't been able to narrow this down yet).  Below is an example Search Builder query that I tried and the resulting error that was in the CiviCRM log file located in the /wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ConfigAndLog directory.

The query was to find Organizations that were Not In two designated groups shown in the image below:
[image]

Not sure if it helps but when I used the Back Key to get back to review my previous query the query screen looked like the following:

[image]

The related error in the CiviCRM log file was:

```
> Apr 27 10:25:32  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array (
>     [callback] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => CRM_Core_Error
>             [1] => handle
>         )
> 
>     [code] => -19
>     [message] => DB Error: no such field
>     [mode] => 16
>     [debug_info] => SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, contact_a.contact_sub_type
> as `contact_sub_type`, contact_a.sort_name as `sort_name`, 
>             CONCAT_WS(',',
>             GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(civicrm_group_contact.status = 'Added', civicrm_group_contact.group_id, '')),
>             GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT civicrm_group_contact_cache.group_id)
>           )
>           as groups   FROM civicrm_contact contact_a  LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact `civicrm_group_contact-43,47` ON (contact_a.id =
> `civicrm_group_contact-43,47`.contact_id AND
> `civicrm_group_contact-43,47`.status IN ('Added'))  WHERE  (  (  ( (
> `civicrm_group_contact-43,47`.group_id NOT IN ( 43,47 )  ) )  AND
> contact_a.contact_type = 'organization' )  )  AND
> (contact_a.is_deleted = 0)   GROUP BY contact_a.id  ORDER BY
> UPPER(LEFT(contact_a.sort_name, 1)) asc  [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown
> column 'civicrm_group_contact.status' in 'field list']
>     [type] => DB_Error
>     [user_info] => SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, contact_a.contact_sub_type
> as `contact_sub_type`, contact_a.sort_name as `sort_name`, 
>             CONCAT_WS(',',
>             GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(civicrm_group_contact.status = 'Added', civicrm_group_contact.group_id, '')),
>             GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT civicrm_group_contact_cache.group_id)
>           )
>           as groups   FROM civicrm_contact contact_a  LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact `civicrm_group_contact-43,47` ON (contact_a.id =
> `civicrm_group_contact-43,47`.contact_id AND
> `civicrm_group_contact-43,47`.status IN ('Added'))  WHERE  (  (  ( (
> `civicrm_group_contact-43,47`.group_id NOT IN ( 43,47 )  ) )  AND
> contact_a.contact_type = 'organization' )  )  AND
> (contact_a.is_deleted = 0)   GROUP BY contact_a.id  ORDER BY
> UPPER(LEFT(contact_a.sort_name, 1)) asc  [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown
> column 'civicrm_group_contact.status' in 'field list']
>     [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such field" code=-19 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix=""
> info="SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as
> `contact_type`, contact_a.contact_sub_type as `contact_sub_type`,
> contact_a.sort_name as `sort_name`, 
>             CONCAT_WS(',',
>             GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(civicrm_group_contact.status = 'Added', civicrm_group_contact.group_id, '')),
>             GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT civicrm_group_contact_cache.group_id)
>           )
>           as groups   FROM civicrm_contact contact_a  LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact `civicrm_group_contact-43,47` ON (contact_a.id =
> `civicrm_group_contact-43,47`.contact_id AND
> `civicrm_group_contact-43,47`.status IN ('Added'))  WHERE  (  (  ( (
> `civicrm_group_contact-43,47`.group_id NOT IN ( 43,47 )  ) )  AND
> contact_a.contact_type = 'organization' )  )  AND
> (contact_a.is_deleted = 0)   GROUP BY contact_a.id  ORDER BY
> UPPER(LEFT(contact_a.sort_name, 1)) asc  [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown
> column 'civicrm_group_contact.status' in 'field list']"] )
> 
> 
> Apr 27 10:25:32  [info] $backTrace = #0
> /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(232):
> CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
> #1 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921):
> CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
> #2 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985):
> PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: no such field", -19, 16, (Array:2),
> "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as
> `contact_type`, ...")
> #3 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575):
> DB_Error->__construct(-19, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT contact_a.id as
> contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, ...")
> #4 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(223):
> PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -19, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT
> contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`,
> ...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
> #5 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905):
> PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
> #6 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933):
> DB_common->raiseError(-19, NULL, NULL, "SELECT contact_a.id as
> contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, ...", "1054 **
> Unknown column 'civicrm_group_contact.status' in 'field list'")
> #7 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403):
> DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
> #8 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216):
> DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id,
> contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, ...")
> #9 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2446):
> DB_common->query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id,
> contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, ...")
> #10 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1635):
> DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id,
> contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, ...")
> #11 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(392):
> DB_DataObject->query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id,
> contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, ...")
> #12 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1348):
> CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id,
> contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, ...", TRUE)
> #13 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(4942):
> CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id,
> contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, ...")
> #14 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Selector.php(1181):
> CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->searchQuery(NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, FALSE,
> TRUE)
> #15 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/PagerAToZ.php(108):
> CRM_Contact_Selector->alphabetQuery()
> #16 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/PagerAToZ.php(136):
> CRM_Utils_PagerAToZ::getDynamicCharacters(Object(CRM_Contact_Selector),
> FALSE)
> #17 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/PagerAToZ.php(52):
> CRM_Utils_PagerAToZ::createLinks(Object(CRM_Contact_Selector), NULL,
> FALSE)
> #18 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search.php(839):
> CRM_Utils_PagerAToZ::getAToZBar(Object(CRM_Contact_Selector), NULL)
> #19 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Builder.php(414):
> CRM_Contact_Form_Search->postProcess()
> #20 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(447):
> CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Builder->postProcess()
> #21 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Refresh.php(75):
> CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
> #22 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203):
> CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Refresh->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Builder),
> "refresh")
> #23 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103):
> HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Builder), "refresh")
> #24 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351):
> HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("refresh")
> #25 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(309):
> CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:4), (Array:0))
> #26 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84):
> CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
> #27 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52):
> CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
> #28 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1246):
> CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
> #29 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
> #30 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
> #31 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
> #32 /home/coloradomaker/www/www/wp-admin/admin.php(224): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
```

Comment: Or rerun your group cache rebuild since i see "Unknown
> column 'civicrm_group_contact.status'" in your error

Comment: I assume you mean removing all files in my template_c directory.  Will give it a try...be back as it takes awhile.

Comment: While waiting...I checked my *Clean-up Temporary Data and Files* scheduled job and it ran with no errors.  It executes hourly.

Comment: After deleting all files under the templates_c directory, I went to *Administer > System Settings > Cleanup Caches and Update Paths* and selected *Cleanup Caches* then *Reset Paths*. Same DB Error using the same Search Builder query above.

Comment: While in the Scheduled Jobs area decided to run some of them related to cache and updates.  The following finished execution with Success (1):  *Update Check* and *Disable expired relationships*.

Comment: In following some of the steps on the System Administrator / Troubleshooting section under Rebuilding triggers I executed the following URL but still did not fix:  http://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2F%25menu%2F%25rebuild%3Freset%3D1&triggerRebuild=1

Comment: I decided to also run the *Rebuild Smart Group Cache* Scheduled Job and it finished execution with Success (1),

Comment: Ran the *Clean-up Temporary Data and Files* job manually. The Full message:  Finished execution of Clean-up Temporary Data and Files with result: Success (empty values!)

Comment: BTW, I am able to go to *Contacts > Manage Groups* and get a list of groups.   When I click on a group it does display the contacts in the group.  Also, I am able to use a Profile that has all my subscription groups (set to *Expose Publicly*), make changes to the groups that I'm subscribed to and save with no errors.

Answer (score 2):

It should be fixed in the latest rc (5.2) https://download.civicrm.org/latest

From ChaosBuster:
Was able to install the latest at this time, 5.1.2, and I am now able to query with the Search Builder for groups for the situation that was mentioned above.

Comment: Also note - this affects sites with mysql mode FULL GROUP BY enabled - you can disable that mode in your sql config

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bug in 5.0.0. The Drupal Demo site (and our 5.0.0 + Drupal 7 site) fails with a similar message if you try to do a search builder search for Contacts > group = or <>. In our site, the error message also involves 'civicrm_group_contact.status' as an unknown field. Naturally, I can't see the log in the demo site, but the error reported on screen is the same.

I don't know how to post a bug... but hope this might help raise one!
(I tried going to the issue tracker, but it's been moved to git hub and I couldn't spot how to report a bug there.)

Comment: I just tried this on our recently updated 5.0.2rc and same behaviour.

Comment: Andyg8, you aren't on rc 5.2, correct? You indicated 5.0.2rc..same as my version.  user4278 indicated a few minutes ago that this was fixed in 5.2.  I will be out all day tomorrow and not willing to do the change the day before, but willing to give it a go later this week.

Comment: Yes, I am on 5.0.2rc. And there is indeed a bug associated with this behaviour - at least in our case: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/106. 
I believe it has been fixed for 5.2rc.

Answer (score 0):

If logging is enabled, try disabling logging and re-enabling logging.  I had a somewhat similar error, but it's different enough that it may not be the same issue.

Comment: I tried this (+ resetting session) before posting.  Thanks for helping me remember though, so others will know.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to [my issue too](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24678/how-to-search-for-all-contacts-without-a-tag-registered-for-event) - in the meantime, i found (due to the great answer Jon gave) that doing search -> custom search -> include / exclude search - I was able to get the results I wanted.