# how to report a bug - and here's a possible bug about groups and search builder

Tags: groups, issues, search-builder

Just flagging this issue a little higher in people's awareness:

On [this issue](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24684), I made a comment about it perhaps being a bug? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/24842/308

So, how do I report that bug? Sorry, I must be missing something obvious in git: I tried going to the issue tracker, but it's been moved to git hub and I couldn't spot how to report a bug there.

Comment: You need to create an issue under https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues

Comment: Thanks Monish. I've done that now. 
Is it worth updating the Civi documentation, https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting, which directs the reader to https://issues.civicrm.org?
Thanks.

Comment: have raised in the Documentation channel on SE

Comment: Ugh - that issue about bug reporting's been raised multiple times.  I'll flag this again.